# Django can not find the css file specified in html file

Tags: python, django

In my Django project, I have a html file :

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

And STATIC_URL = '/static/' in settings.py. My urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', WelcomeView.as_view(), name='welcome'),
)
```

My Django project can NOT FIND the `bootstrap.css` file in `/static/` directory. Should I add a url in `urls.py`? And what should I write this url?

When my html file is:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static bootstrap/bootstrap.css %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

The brower says " TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: 'bootstrap/bootstrap.css' from 'bootstrap/bootstrap.css' "

My settings.py is:

```
    import os
import sys

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)


ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

if ROOT_PATH not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(ROOT_PATH)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, '..', 'static'))
#STATIC_ROOT = /home/mysite/static

TEMPLATE_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'templates')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Comment: Double check your directory structure. Make sure your static files must be placed inside `static` directory of **each** app. In above case, Django tries to read `bootstrap.css` file within `static` directory under an application called `bootstrap`.

Comment: Have you followed all of the steps here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/ ?

Comment: Is `DEBUG = False` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: Is your static folder in your project directory? (Next to settings.py?) If so, try adding the name of your project to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Please put the settings.py

Comment: Path to the static file need to be wrapped in quotes: `{% static "bootstrap/bootstrap.css" %}`

Comment: are you running under the Django dev server, i.e. `manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: When I use {% load static %}
    <link href="{% static bootstrap/bootstrap.css %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"> in html file. There is a problem " TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '/bootstrap.css' from 'bootstrap/bootstrap.css' "

Answer (score 0):

Do you directory looks like below:

```
-youproject
|___static
|   |___ bootstrap
|       |___bootstrap.css
|___templates
|   |___yourhtml.html
|___vies.py
|___models.py
```

My django project is just like that.So,check your project's directory.

wish can help you.

Comment: How do you create a Django project ? I use django-admin.py startproject projectname to create a project . what about you ?

Comment: yes,me too! django-admin.py startproject projectname to create a project .Then use python manage.py startapp appname to create a app.@changzhi

Comment: Ok, What is the version of your django ?